# How to handle when call requests at same time

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot create a restful for save data to Database.
Now I have problem when you call this service in the same time my data its duplicated in database because previous request not finish yet.

I generate number like 00001 I need to running its from database

1. I get last from DB
2. then 00001+1 = 00002
3. save to Database

but when request same time in database save 00002 for 2 records.

```
     @Transactional
public List<Object> saveData(String data) {
 //validate data
 //Get Last Data    
 //set prepare data
 //save data
    int idLatest = Integer.parseInt(getLatest("7", "8"));
    List<Object> objects = autoGenarateEntity(idLatest);
    Repository.save(Object);

}

   public String getLatest(String idFirst, String idSecond){
    Optional<Object> running = Repository.findByBIdStartingWithOrderByBIdDesc(idFirst, idSecond).stream().findFirst();
    if(running.isPresent()){
        String bId =running.get();
        return bId.getBId();
    }else {
        return "70000000";
    }

}

   public List<Object> autoGenarateEntity(int idLatest){
    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.range(1, 5 + 1).forEach(i -> {
        Object obj = new Object();
        obj.setBId(Integer.toString(idLatest + i));

        obj.add(Object);
    });
    return objects;
}
```

Comment: you could have unique key constraint for the column having the value of 00001. So as a result, the second transaction which was trying to commit same value would roll-back

Comment: This is old table has duplicated data in this table.

Comment: Please, show more information about your case, the code samples, unless we make assumptions, and guesses.

Comment: @BSeitkazin ok.

Comment: It looks like you have some logic error, looking at your `saveData` function, I see, you request `idLatest` int value, but you don't use it. Show up the whole

Comment: @BSeitkazin ok.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the options that can be done in this case:

1.) have unique key constraint for the column having the value of 00001. So that, the second transaction which was trying to commit same value would roll-back.
And you could use Spring-Retry mechanism to execute the second transaction with updated value

2.) Use a custom sequence Generator to increment the value, instead of handling it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this

```
 @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
```

and use spring retry